# How to add active-trail class to a links in a view?

Tags: views, routes

How to add an active-trail class to all links in a view, which a parents of a current page (according to a result of menu_get_active_trail())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add an invisible PHP-field to a view (let the field identifier will be php).

Set a setup code to

```
$static = module_exists('crumbs') ? crumbs_get_trail() : menu_get_active_trail();
```

Set a value code to

```
$href = 'taxonomy/term/' . $data->tid;
foreach ($static as $item) {
  if ($item['href'] === $href) {
    return 'active-trail';
  }
}
```

And at last add a custom CSS class to a link field with token [php]